# How to make a minimum size exe for inference of a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to share a model that I trained. I am currently trying to use Pyinstaller to make an exe. It's really huge ! 300 MB at least.

Is there any way to use anything else to make inference out of a saved model ?

I tried using tensorflow lite but my ops are not supported.

I am kind of looking for a tensorflow-inference-only package.

Thanks,

Comment: The huge part of your exe may come from the library you are using. Try to import only the needed function and not the entiere library (import yourneededfunction from yourneeded library)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to decrease the size of your exe file
you need to minimize the import statements

for example you are using random so you `import random` but you only use `random.choice`

so it's better to use `from random import choice`

doing this can decrease your file size !

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's usefull to know but it looks like it doesn't work on tensorflow.

`from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model` is what i tried to load.